# Decrypt without losing data

Tags: javascript

1. Why crypto JS files? I see that 1 in 10 have crypted Javascript. Would it be useful information?
2. http://pastebin.com/Upqy9xmx - as an example of one of the files, which is encoded.
   Is it possible to find out what it is coded, and is there any possibility to decrypt it without losing data?

Comment: What are you trying to do here?  What's your question?  What are you trying to "decrypt"?

Comment: I think you're asking what is the purpose of minified and concatenated javascript, which should be easy to google for. A javascript "beautifier" can re-indent the lines and give some information back.

Comment: Are you referring to obfuscating files? If so, then the benefits are impeded visibility to public viewers as well as smaller file size due to the lack of tabs, extra whitespace, etc.

Nothing has been changed functionality wise and it although it is possible to unobfuscate, you should have a copy of the original regardless.

Comment: Your script beautified http://codebeautify.org/jsviewer/109593.

Comment: @DipenShah thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Almost nobody encrypts JavaScript files (except when in transit over HTTPS because loading non-SSL traffic into SSL traffic is a huge security issue). Quite a lot of people *minify* JS, which is done to reduce the bandwidth needed to transfer the script so it loads faster.

The file you link to is an example of that. You can use a code formatter to restore new lines and indents, but once a human readable variable name as been replaced by a very short variable name, there is nothing you can do to get it back.

Modernizr is an open source library though, you can get the human readable version from their website.